# Safari extension that saves a window's tabs

Tags: osx, safari

I'm looking for an extension that can save a window's worth of open tabs and reopen those tabs later.

I often find myself with a window with 8+ tabs open to various pages on a subject. Researching that subject isn't urgent, so I want to close the window for a while (saving battery) and come back to it later.

Required: Works with Safari 7, the current release. Nice to have: Saves full tab history, not just current URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari has a [built-in feature](http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2012/10/saving-browser-tab-sets/) for that:

[image]

Both of these commands create a folder with bookmarks to every tab. All the bookmarks can be opened at a later date with a single menu selection:

[image]

Comment: So obvious I missed it.